# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'baseMapper'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

**I checked the mapping path several times.**

**I also added the MapperScan annotation.but the error still exist.**

**I have no choice.**

**Thanks in advance.**

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

@MapperScan("com.zhu.mapper")

public class FamilyServicePlatformApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FamilyServicePlatformApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mashibing</groupId>
    <artifactId>family_service_platform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>family_service_platform</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--mybatis代码快速生成-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.yaml**

```
server:
  port: 8080


spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/family_service_platform?serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: 123456
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:com/zhu/mapper/*.xml
  configuration:
    map-underscore-to-camel-case: true

logging:
  level:
    com:
      zhu:
        mapper: debug
```

**It is my part of project This is part of my project structure**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtp1z.png)

**This is part of the error message**

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-12 17:17:47.910 ERROR 30904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fcBuildingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'baseMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fcBuildingMapper' defined in file [D:\Software engineering\family_service_platform\target\classes\com\zhu\mapper\FcBuildingMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

**FcBuildingMapper.java**

```
package com.zhu.mapper;

import com.zhu.bean.FcBuilding;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

/**
 * <p>
 * 楼宇信息表 Mapper 接口
 * </p>
 *
 * @author lian
 * @since 2022-01-12
 */

public interface FcBuildingMapper extends BaseMapper<FcBuilding> {

}
```

**FcBuildingMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.zhu.mapper.FcBuildingMapper">

    <!-- 通用查询映射结果 -->
    <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.zhu.bean.FcBuilding">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result column="estate_code" property="estateCode" />
        <result column="building_code" property="buildingCode" />
        <result column="building_name" property="buildingName" />
        <result column="building_function" property="buildingFunction" />
        <result column="used_area" property="usedArea" />
        <result column="build_area" property="buildArea" />
        <result column="build_permission_id" property="buildPermissionId" />
        <result column="sale_permission_id" property="salePermissionId" />
        <result column="finish_date" property="finishDate" />
        <result column="over_roof_date" property="overRoofDate" />
        <result column="decorate" property="decorate" />
        <result column="struct_type" property="structType" />
        <result column="damage_grade" property="damageGrade" />
        <result column="unit_count" property="unitCount" />
        <result column="building_type" property="buildingType" />
        <result column="clean_floor" property="cleanFloor" />
        <result column="mop_floor" property="mopFloor" />
        <result column="channel_area" property="channelArea" />
        <result column="elevator" property="elevator" />
        <result column="channel_door" property="channelDoor" />
        <result column="evevator_door" property="evevatorDoor" />
        <result column="water_well_door" property="waterWellDoor" />
        <result column="electric_well_door" property="electricWellDoor" />
        <result column="window_shades" property="windowShades" />
        <result column="hydrant" property="hydrant" />
        <result column="mirrors" property="mirrors" />
        <result column="unit_door" property="unitDoor" />
        <result column="harden_ground_area" property="hardenGroundArea" />
        <result column="green_area" property="greenArea" />
        <result column="no_green_area" property="noGreenArea" />
        <result column="water_by_person" property="waterByPerson" />
        <result column="is_elevator" property="isElevator" />
        <result column="is_second_water_electric" property="isSecondWaterElectric" />
        <result column="random_identify" property="randomIdentify" />
        <result column="remark" property="remark" />
    </resultMap>

    <!-- 通用查询结果列 -->
    <sql id="Base_Column_List">
        id, estate_code, building_code, building_name, building_function, used_area, build_area, build_permission_id, sale_permission_id, finish_date, over_roof_date, decorate, struct_type, damage_grade, unit_count, building_type, clean_floor, mop_floor, channel_area, elevator, channel_door, evevator_door, water_well_door, electric_well_door, window_shades, hydrant, mirrors, unit_door, harden_ground_area, green_area, no_green_area, water_by_person, is_elevator, is_second_water_electric, random_identify, remark
    </sql>

</mapper>
```

**FcBuildingServiceImpl**

```
package com.zhu.service.impl;

import com.zhu.bean.FcBuilding;
import com.zhu.mapper.FcBuildingMapper;
import com.zhu.service.FcBuildingService;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.impl.ServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * <p>
 * 楼宇信息表 服务实现类
 * </p>
 *
 * @author lian
 * @since 2022-01-12
 */
@Service
public class FcBuildingServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl<FcBuildingMapper, FcBuilding> implements FcBuildingService {

}
```

**FcBuildingService**

```
package com.zhu.service;

import com.zhu.bean.FcBuilding;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.IService;

/**
 * <p>
 * 楼宇信息表 服务类
 * </p>
 *
 * @author lian
 * @since 2022-01-12
 */
public interface FcBuildingService extends IService<FcBuilding> {

}
```

**FcBuildingController**

```
package com.zhu.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

/**
 * <p>
 * 楼宇信息表 前端控制器
 * </p>
 *
 * @author lian
 * @since 2022-01-12
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fcBuilding")
public class FcBuildingController {

}
```

**FcBuilding**

```
package com.zhu.bean;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.IdType;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.TableId;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * <p>
 * 楼宇信息表
 * </p>
 *
 * @author lian
 * @since 2022-01-12
 */
public class FcBuilding implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    /**
     * 自动编号
     */
    @TableId(value = "id", type = IdType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    /**
     * 房产编码
     */
    private String estateCode;

    /**
     * 楼宇编码
     */
    private String buildingCode;

    /**
     * 楼宇名称
     */
    private String buildingName;

    /**
     * 楼宇功能
     */
    private String buildingFunction;

    /**
     * 使用面积
     */
    private Double usedArea;

    /**
     * 建筑面积
     */
    private Double buildArea;

    /**
     * 建设许可证号
     */
    private String buildPermissionId;

    /**
     * 销售许可证号
     */
    private String salePermissionId;

    /**
     * 竣工日期
     */
    private LocalDateTime finishDate;

    /**
     * 封顶日期
     */
    private LocalDateTime overRoofDate;

    /**
     * 装修
     */
    private String decorate;

    /**
     * 结构类别
     */
    private String structType;

    /**
     * 完损等级
     */
    private String damageGrade;

    /**
     * 单元数量
     */
    private Double unitCount;

    /**
     * 楼宇类型
     */
    private String buildingType;

    /**
     * 清扫层数
     */
    private Integer cleanFloor;

    /**
     * 拖洗层数
     */
    private Integer mopFloor;

    /**
     * 楼狼通道地面
     */
    private Double channelArea;

    /**
     * 电梯轿箱
     */
    private Integer elevator;

    /**
     * 通道门
     */
    private Integer channelDoor;

    /**
     * 电梯门
     */
    private Integer evevatorDoor;

    /**
     * 水井门
     */
    private Integer waterWellDoor;

    /**
     * 电井门
     */
    private Integer electricWellDoor;

    /**
     * 百叶窗
     */
    private Integer windowShades;

    /**
     * 消防栓
     */
    private Integer hydrant;

    /**
     * 整容镜
     */
    private Integer mirrors;

    /**
     * 单元门
     */
    private Integer unitDoor;

    /**
     * 硬化地面
     */
    private Double hardenGroundArea;

    /**
     * 提纯绿地
     */
    private Double greenArea;

    /**
     * 不提纯绿地
     */
    private Double noGreenArea;

    /**
     * 人工水面
     */
    private Double waterByPerson;

    /**
     * 是否使用电梯
     */
    private String isElevator;

    /**
     * 是否需要二次水电
     */
    private String isSecondWaterElectric;

    /**
     * 随机标识码
     */
    private String randomIdentify;

    /**
     * 备注
     */
    private String remark;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEstateCode() {
        return estateCode;
    }

    public void setEstateCode(String estateCode) {
        this.estateCode = estateCode;
    }

    public String getBuildingCode() {
        return buildingCode;
    }

    public void setBuildingCode(String buildingCode) {
        this.buildingCode = buildingCode;
    }

    public String getBuildingName() {
        return buildingName;
    }

    public void setBuildingName(String buildingName) {
        this.buildingName = buildingName;
    }

    public String getBuildingFunction() {
        return buildingFunction;
    }

    public void setBuildingFunction(String buildingFunction) {
        this.buildingFunction = buildingFunction;
    }

    public Double getUsedArea() {
        return usedArea;
    }

    public void setUsedArea(Double usedArea) {
        this.usedArea = usedArea;
    }

    public Double getBuildArea() {
        return buildArea;
    }

    public void setBuildArea(Double buildArea) {
        this.buildArea = buildArea;
    }

    public String getBuildPermissionId() {
        return buildPermissionId;
    }

    public void setBuildPermissionId(String buildPermissionId) {
        this.buildPermissionId = buildPermissionId;
    }

    public String getSalePermissionId() {
        return salePermissionId;
    }

    public void setSalePermissionId(String salePermissionId) {
        this.salePermissionId = salePermissionId;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getFinishDate() {
        return finishDate;
    }

    public void setFinishDate(LocalDateTime finishDate) {
        this.finishDate = finishDate;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getOverRoofDate() {
        return overRoofDate;
    }

    public void setOverRoofDate(LocalDateTime overRoofDate) {
        this.overRoofDate = overRoofDate;
    }

    public String getDecorate() {
        return decorate;
    }

    public void setDecorate(String decorate) {
        this.decorate = decorate;
    }

    public String getStructType() {
        return structType;
    }

    public void setStructType(String structType) {
        this.structType = structType;
    }

    public String getDamageGrade() {
        return damageGrade;
    }

    public void setDamageGrade(String damageGrade) {
        this.damageGrade = damageGrade;
    }

    public Double getUnitCount() {
        return unitCount;
    }

    public void setUnitCount(Double unitCount) {
        this.unitCount = unitCount;
    }

    public String getBuildingType() {
        return buildingType;
    }

    public void setBuildingType(String buildingType) {
        this.buildingType = buildingType;
    }

    public Integer getCleanFloor() {
        return cleanFloor;
    }

    public void setCleanFloor(Integer cleanFloor) {
        this.cleanFloor = cleanFloor;
    }

    public Integer getMopFloor() {
        return mopFloor;
    }

    public void setMopFloor(Integer mopFloor) {
        this.mopFloor = mopFloor;
    }

    public Double getChannelArea() {
        return channelArea;
    }

    public void setChannelArea(Double channelArea) {
        this.channelArea = channelArea;
    }

    public Integer getElevator() {
        return elevator;
    }

    public void setElevator(Integer elevator) {
        this.elevator = elevator;
    }

    public Integer getChannelDoor() {
        return channelDoor;
    }

    public void setChannelDoor(Integer channelDoor) {
        this.channelDoor = channelDoor;
    }

    public Integer getEvevatorDoor() {
        return evevatorDoor;
    }

    public void setEvevatorDoor(Integer evevatorDoor) {
        this.evevatorDoor = evevatorDoor;
    }

    public Integer getWaterWellDoor() {
        return waterWellDoor;
    }

    public void setWaterWellDoor(Integer waterWellDoor) {
        this.waterWellDoor = waterWellDoor;
    }

    public Integer getElectricWellDoor() {
        return electricWellDoor;
    }

    public void setElectricWellDoor(Integer electricWellDoor) {
        this.electricWellDoor = electricWellDoor;
    }

    public Integer getWindowShades() {
        return windowShades;
    }

    public void setWindowShades(Integer windowShades) {
        this.windowShades = windowShades;
    }

    public Integer getHydrant() {
        return hydrant;
    }

    public void setHydrant(Integer hydrant) {
        this.hydrant = hydrant;
    }

    public Integer getMirrors() {
        return mirrors;
    }

    public void setMirrors(Integer mirrors) {
        this.mirrors = mirrors;
    }

    public Integer getUnitDoor() {
        return unitDoor;
    }

    public void setUnitDoor(Integer unitDoor) {
        this.unitDoor = unitDoor;
    }

    public Double getHardenGroundArea() {
        return hardenGroundArea;
    }

    public void setHardenGroundArea(Double hardenGroundArea) {
        this.hardenGroundArea = hardenGroundArea;
    }

    public Double getGreenArea() {
        return greenArea;
    }

    public void setGreenArea(Double greenArea) {
        this.greenArea = greenArea;
    }

    public Double getNoGreenArea() {
        return noGreenArea;
    }

    public void setNoGreenArea(Double noGreenArea) {
        this.noGreenArea = noGreenArea;
    }

    public Double getWaterByPerson() {
        return waterByPerson;
    }

    public void setWaterByPerson(Double waterByPerson) {
        this.waterByPerson = waterByPerson;
    }

    public String getIsElevator() {
        return isElevator;
    }

    public void setIsElevator(String isElevator) {
        this.isElevator = isElevator;
    }

    public String getIsSecondWaterElectric() {
        return isSecondWaterElectric;
    }

    public void setIsSecondWaterElectric(String isSecondWaterElectric) {
        this.isSecondWaterElectric = isSecondWaterElectric;
    }

    public String getRandomIdentify() {
        return randomIdentify;
    }

    public void setRandomIdentify(String randomIdentify) {
        this.randomIdentify = randomIdentify;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FcBuilding{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", estateCode=" + estateCode +
        ", buildingCode=" + buildingCode +
        ", buildingName=" + buildingName +
        ", buildingFunction=" + buildingFunction +
        ", usedArea=" + usedArea +
        ", buildArea=" + buildArea +
        ", buildPermissionId=" + buildPermissionId +
        ", salePermissionId=" + salePermissionId +
        ", finishDate=" + finishDate +
        ", overRoofDate=" + overRoofDate +
        ", decorate=" + decorate +
        ", structType=" + structType +
        ", damageGrade=" + damageGrade +
        ", unitCount=" + unitCount +
        ", buildingType=" + buildingType +
        ", cleanFloor=" + cleanFloor +
        ", mopFloor=" + mopFloor +
        ", channelArea=" + channelArea +
        ", elevator=" + elevator +
        ", channelDoor=" + channelDoor +
        ", evevatorDoor=" + evevatorDoor +
        ", waterWellDoor=" + waterWellDoor +
        ", electricWellDoor=" + electricWellDoor +
        ", windowShades=" + windowShades +
        ", hydrant=" + hydrant +
        ", mirrors=" + mirrors +
        ", unitDoor=" + unitDoor +
        ", hardenGroundArea=" + hardenGroundArea +
        ", greenArea=" + greenArea +
        ", noGreenArea=" + noGreenArea +
        ", waterByPerson=" + waterByPerson +
        ", isElevator=" + isElevator +
        ", isSecondWaterElectric=" + isSecondWaterElectric +
        ", randomIdentify=" + randomIdentify +
        ", remark=" + remark +
        "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is occuring for FcBuildingServiceImpl, so please show the code for that, and any related XML file.

Comment: I've added some new code.Please look it over again .Thank you!

Comment: I just want to mention your error is this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required`, so maybe search on that